# How to detect the rowspan for same element values?

Tags: xslt

I have the following input:

```
<input>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>4</cell>
  </row>
</input>
```

and I would like to have the following output:

```
<output>
  <row>
    <cell rowspan="4">7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>7</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell rowspan="3">5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>5</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell rowspan="1">4</cell>
  </row>
</output>
```

It means I would like to add `rowspan` only if values are the same. But how to compute the value for `rowspan`?

I did the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<output>
  <xsl:for-each select="//input/row">
    <row>
      <cell>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::row[1]/cell = cell)">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">?</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="cell" />
      </cell>
    </row>
  </xsl:for-each>
</output>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I don't know how to compute the number for `rowspan`.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- P.S. Are you sure you want to indicate the rowspan **and** leave the duplicate cells in place?

Comment: I'm using 1.0. Maybe I will remove duplicate cells, this is not a problem... I just want to calculate the proper number for `rowspan`.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I will remove duplicate cells, this is not a problem...

Well, it makes a difference, as you will see.

Here's one way you could look at this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <xsl:variable name="total-rows" select="count(row)" />
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[not(cell=preceding-sibling::row[1]/cell)]">
            <row>
                <cell>
                    <xsl:if test="cell=following-sibling::row[1]/cell">
                        <xsl:variable name="p1" select="count(preceding-sibling::row)" />
                        <xsl:variable name="next-change" select="following-sibling::row[not(cell=current()/cell)][1]" />
                        <xsl:variable name="p2">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$next-change">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="count($next-change/preceding-sibling::row)" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$total-rows" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$p2 - $p1" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cell" />
                </cell>
            </row>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result, when applied to your example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <row>
      <cell rowspan="4">7</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell rowspan="3">5</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>4</cell>
   </row>
</output>
```

Note that this constant counting of preceding siblings is not very efficient; hopefully you won't have a very large number of rows.

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm afraid it will be not enough for me... The input file is just a sample file, I have to iterate on every `cell` with `for-each`. Isn't it possible to iterate twice on the input file?

Comment: "*I have to iterate on every cell with for-each*" I am afraid I don't know what you mean by that.